# How to escape a word in a query string?

Tags: escaping, query-string, reserved-words

I have a URL that looks like this more or less:

www.xyz.com?parameter1=value&region=global

The problem is that some browsers are literally changing &reg into ® so the URL is breaking because it's turning into either

www.xyz.com?parameter1=value®ion=global
or
www.xyz.com?parameter1=value%AEion=global

Is there a way to escape out a value like that for URL web queries? Or is it best to just avoid certain character combinations?

(the manual fix is to swap the parameters around so it's ?reg instead of &reg but that's an annoying manual intervention every time...)

Answer (score 0):

Used this link here.
It helped me Although it was described as for Java, you can play with it to sort your issue

[Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)